# VBA Function Not Working with nested loops

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a function in Excel VBA which checks each word in a string, and if a word from the string is located in a keyword bank located in a different Excel sheet.

If it is a positive word, it gets a score of 10, and if it is a negative word, it gets a score of -10. After the function reads through the string it calculates the total and prints the output total.

I have to remove `$!.,` and `?` from the string before doing the calculation. I'm supposed to use `StrComp`, `Split`, and `Remove` which I have done. I'm also supposed to use nested loops:

- one for each word in the keywords,
- and one for each string text.

Here is my code below that doesn't seem to want to work for me. Any help on getting this to run would be extremely helpful:

Function sentimentCalc(tweet As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim positiveworda As String, negativewords As String
    Dim positive As Range, negative As Range
    Dim tweetcleaned As String
    Dim count As Integer

```
Set positive = Worksheets("keywords").Range("A2:A53")
Set negative = Worksheets("keywords").Range("B2:B53")

tweetwords = Split(tweet, " ")
positivewords = Split(positive, " ")
negativewords = Split(negative, " ")

    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, "$", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, "!", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, ".", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, ",", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, "?", "")

    tweetcleaned = tweet

count = 0

For i = LBound(tweetwords) To UBound(tweetwords)
    For j = LBound(positiveword) To UBound(positiveword)
        If StrComp(tweetwords(i), "positivewords()", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
           count = count + 10
           Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    For k = LBound(negativeword) To UBound(negativeword)
        If StrComp(tweetwords(i), "negativewords()", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
           count = count - 10
           Exit For
        End If
    Next k
Next i

sentimentCalc = count
End Function
```

Comment: You are missing an EndIf in the first loop

Comment: What does `Print value` do? `Debug.Print`?

Comment: *Here is my code below that doesn't seem to want to work for me.* What is the problem?

Comment: you defined `keywordsnegative As String` so it throws an "*Error 13 type mismatch*" at `keywordsnegative = Split(negative, " ")` because it has to be an array like `keywordsnegative() As String`. If you omit the brackets `()` after the variable name it is just a string. With brackets it is an array of strings. `Split` returns an array! For future questions please always include your error message and tell in which position of the code they occur.

Comment: You can't use `Split` on Range. You can't use `Replace` on arrays.

Comment: You can't use `StrComp` on array either, and you don't have nested loops in your code, so your title is not very well chosen.

Comment: Your `Exit For` seems to be in the wrong place.

Comment: where would it go? @JahKnows

Comment: Oh ok I see, can you indent your code such that its readable.

Comment: So if the `if` statement is satisfied then you want to stop the loop directly? This will only identify a single positive word?

Comment: @JahKnows its indented exactly like it is in vba.  No, it will only count the matched keyword once. So it stops the loop for that keyword if it is matched, then moves to the next keyword.

Comment: "its indented exactly like it is in vba", what does that even mean? The code is written with poor formatting. VBA does not have indentation rules. You can write the entire code on a single line. However, it is poor form. Indentation is essential for readability.

Comment: @JahKnows it means, that is how I indented it to make sense when I wrote it. Not exactly sure how I would indent it any different.

Comment: I indented it. Notice that the `Exit For` should be contained in the if statement, thus it should be in line with the code within that `if` statement.

Comment: Can I see your spreadsheet such that I can reproduce the error please?

Comment: @JahKnows I just tried it with your edits, and it still returns the same error. Yes I will post it.

Comment: The indentation does not affect the code operation. You can write all the code on a single line. VBA language is not affected by spacing or line breaks. It only affects readability. How can we read code that's all mumbled together?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166722/discussion-between-brad-and-jahknows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
Function sentimentCalc(tweet As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim positiveworda As String, negativewords, word As String
    Dim positive As Range, negative As Range
    Dim tweetcleaned As String
    Dim count As Integer

    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, "$", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, "!", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, ".", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, ",", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, "?", "")

    tweetwords = Split(tweetcleaned, " ")

    count = 0
    For i = LBound(tweetwords) To UBound(tweetwords)
        For j = 1 To 53
            word = Worksheets("keywords").Cells(j, 1)
            If StrComp(tweetwords(i), word, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
               count = count + 10
               Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        For k = 1 To 53
            word = Worksheets("keywords").Cells(j, 2)
            If StrComp(tweetwords(i), word, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
               count = count - 10
               Exit For
            End If
        Next k
    Next i

    sentimentCalc = count
End Function
```

Here is the same method but for a variable number of positive and negative words contained in the 3rd sheet.

```
Function sentimentCalc(tweet As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim positiveworda As String, negativewords, word As String
    Dim positive As Range, negative As Range
    Dim tweetcleaned As String
    Dim count As Integer

    MsgBox tweet

    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, "$", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, "!", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, ".", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, ",", "")
    tweetcleaned = Replace(tweet, "?", "")

    tweetwords = Split(tweetcleaned, " ")

    num_pos_words = Worksheets("keywords").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    num_neg_words = Worksheets("keywords").Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row

    count = 0
    For i = LBound(tweetwords) To UBound(tweetwords)
        For j = 1 To num_pos_words
            If StrComp(tweetwords(i), Worksheets("keywords").Cells(j, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
               count = count + 10
               Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        For k = 1 To num_neg_words
            If StrComp(tweetwords(i), Worksheets("keywords").Cells(j, 2), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
               count = count - 10
               Exit For
            End If
        Next k
    Next i

    sentimentCalc = count
End Function
```

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: I made it more general. Use that one instead, otherwise you may run into issues when you add words to the positive and negative list.